# Angular Material Table row update with popup only 1st array values are coming in all edit rows

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material-table

created app with two components(A&B) with popup dialog on edit:

- Comp A Fetch the data from service and load to the data table
- Comb B initiates the data when pop event fired from A.

typically multiple records are load with array response into the table.

when pop is fired form data loaded correctly for record 1  for record 2 the same value of 1 is getting loaded instead of 2.

used `MAT_DIALOG_DATA` to import the table data to B Component.

a unique record to populate in form B

A_component.ts:

```
open() const dialogconfig = new MatDialogConfig(); 
dialogconfig.diableClose =true; 

this.dialog.open(BComoonent,
{ 
  data: this.datasource
});
```

BComponent.ts

```
constructor(@inject((MAT_DIALOG_DATA public) data:any;)
```

and HTML Code:

```
<input matInput placeholder="First Name " id="" name=" [ngModel]="data[0].empName">
```

Comment: Nice. So show us your code please.

Comment: A component code ts     open() const dialogconfig = new MatDialogConfig();                  dialogconfig.diableClose =true;                                                                                                this.dialog.ope(BComoonent name ,{ data: this.datasource}--which contains reocord.

Comment: component B  code .ts      
constructor (@inject((MAT_DIALOG_DATA public) data:any;)                                                                                                                         
html code                                                                                                     
 <input matInput placeholder="First Name "  id="" name="" [ngModel]="data[0].empName">      
typically when i observe and change the [ngModel]="datat[1].emName">  
i see differnt values other than array.the array 1 data for all rows

Answer (score 0):

The same value is displayed in the dialog because you are explicitly binding the input element value via `ngModel` to the first row of your data in this line:

```
<input matInput placeholder="First Name " id="" name=" [ngModel]="data[0].empName">
```

> **data[0].empName** will always display the `empName` of the first record because you are directly accessing it via `data[0]`.

What you should do instead is, passing only the row you want to edit and not the complete datasource.

In your component A you need to replace your datasource with the row the edit action was fired on:

```
this.dialog.open(BComponent,
{ 
  data: this.datasource // --> change this to the row you want to edit
});
```

And in your dialog you can then access the data without the index, as it is not an array e.g. not the complete datasource:

```
<input matInput placeholder="First Name " id="" name=" [ngModel]="data.empName">
```

Comment: Appreciate your response and I could say this works well :)

Comment: One more trouble to posting the data to api , my api requesting  three parameters as 1 :1 and 2:2 and json body. the dialog form is reactive form. Can we extract the Params and send this to service?